# Debugging on windows phone 8.1 : Access to temporary files

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

When debugging a Windows Phone 8.1 application (working in Visual Studio), with the phone connected to a PC, is there a way to browse and download files from the application's temporary file folder ( Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.currenttemporaryFolder) - or other application folders for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated to incorporate @Youval_Bronicki 's comment*

There are several clients available:

- [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/)
- [ISO Store Spy](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/)
- [Isolated Storage Explorer tool for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408) (a command line tool).

Comment: Thanks!  There is also Microsoft's terminal-based [Isolated Storage Explorer Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408)